How to unset SHELLOPTS monitor:notify?
I like getting notified immediately when a background process exits. To do that one uses:
$ set -b

When you do that, it sets the shell option, contained in the BUILTIN variable SHELLOPTS, called "monitor"; it changes from just "monitor" to "monitor:notify".
But what if I want to return it to the default status of only giving notification when the shell is about to issue a new prompt?
I tried unset with the following result:
$ unset -b
bash: unset: -b: invalid option
unset: usage: unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]

It obviously doesn't work!
I dug through the BASH man page and looked under the shopt command but didn't find anything that addressed this, but then perhaps I didn't recognize what I was looking for.

set +b or set +o notify to revert set -b / set -o notify.

All the options you set with - followed by a single letter can be unset by using + followed by the same letter.  e.g.
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /      # The shell will echo something like "+ cd /"
ls        # See "+ ls'" and then the ls' output
set +x    # See "set +x", as the -x is in effect at the start
cd /dev   # No output as the set -x has been turned off
ls        # see the output of ls

